# Excel: CountIFS - multiple criteria AND not blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data set in which I want to use Countifs and Sumifs to help summarise data.

All this data is held on the sheet "Tank" (just so you know why that name is there later).

For the Countifs I have three formulas, each having a criteria of, blank, not blank and all respectively.

```
=COUNTIFS(Tank!J6:J10000,"International",Tank!H6:10000,1,Tank!R6:R10000,"")
=COUNTIFS(Tank!J6:J10000,"International",Tank!H6:10000,1,Tank!R6:R10000,"<>")
=COUNTIFS(Tank!J6:J10000,"International",Tank!H6:10000,1)
```

However, when I try to use this approach for SUMIFS it returns #VALUE

```
=SUMIFS(Tank!M6:M10000,Tank!:J6:J1000,"International",Tank!H6:H10000,1,Tank!R6:R10000,"")   

=SUMIFS(Tank!M6:M100000,Tank!:J6:J1000,"International",Tank!H6:H10000,1,Tank!R6:R10000,"<>")

 =SUMIFS(Tank!M6:M10000,Tank!:J6:J1000,"International",Tank!H6:H10000,1)
```

What do I need to do to get it return a sum value for me?

EDIT: For future, I have tried combinations of these formulas, using just one two or all three criteria (now I've updated J to 10000) and the error seems to occur only when the "" or "<>" is used.

EDIT 2: SAMPLES

[image]

I would expect the code currently to sum the cost for these jobs with the last criteria deeming if the job is open or now.

Therefore if the formulas are in the same order as I typed before I should get the following amounts:

1 - Open Jobs =5,000

2 - Closed Jobs = 3,000

3 - All Jobs = 8,000

Comment: The ranges need to be the same size - you're missing a zero in the second one.

Comment: I've just tried this and it still isn't working. I've done an attempt at troubleshooting by making combinations of these formulae and it seems like the error is in that last criteria, with both the "" and "<>" as any time thats use it goes wrong?

Comment: Please show some data sample and expected results.

Comment: I've tested in Excel and it works perfectly with `"<>"` and `""`,. so checked again your formulas and you have an extra `:` You typed `=SUMIFS(Tank!M6:M10000,Tank!:J6:J1000,"International",Tank!H6:H10000,1,Tank!R6:R10000,"")`. Check where it says `Tank!:J6:J1000`. You have an extra `:` between `Tank!` and your range. It should be `Tank!J6:J1000`